# Show product details in page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to show products details in a page.

My `aspx` is like below...

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 no-margin product-item-holder hover"> <!-- this div will be repeated for each product -->
<div class="product-item">
    <div class="image">
        <img runat="server" id="img" alt="" src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="label-discount clear"></div>
        <div class="title">
            <a runat="server" id="name" href="single-product.html"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prices">
        <div class="price-prev"></div>
        <div runat="server" id="price" class="price-current pull-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hover-area">
        <div class="add-cart-button">
            <a href="single-product.html" class="le-button">Enquiry</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and my codebehind is like below...

```
dbConnection cn = new dbConnection();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        getLoopData();
    }
}

public void getLoopData()
{
    cn.con.Open();
    cn.cmd.Connection = cn.con;
    cn.cmd.CommandText = "select * FROM products";
    MySqlDataReader reader = cn.cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
        name.InnerText = reader["InventionName"].ToString();
        price.InnerText = reader["Price"].ToString();
        img.Src = reader["Picture"].ToString();

    }
    reader.Close();
    cn.con.Close();
}
```

But it is showing only last product details.

How should I repeat the `div` for each product and how to show every products in page ??

Comment: You should consider using an `asp:repeater`.

Comment: Yea because you are not having it in `array` or as `list`. you might need to dynamically create structure and append it in `div`. Since you are getting it as `id` only last product gets assigned

Answer (score 2):

You can use Asp Repeater to do that.
Check this link out : http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need a datagrid control, repeater or similar to show tabular data. 
Right now you only have one control per attribute to show all records, that's why last one wins.

Answer (score 1):

Your view/page could be like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ProductRepeater" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <div class="product-item">
        <div class="image">
    <img id="img" alt="" src='<%# Eval("Picture") %>' />
               ///...
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

In your code you could do this:

```
cn.con.Open();
cn.cmd.Connection = cn.con;
cn.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT InventionName, Price, Picture FROM products";
MySqlDataReader reader = cn.cmd.ExecuteReader();
ProductRepeater.DataSource = reader;
ProductRepeater.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating a list, and assigning data to `name`, `price` and `img.Src`, but you overwrite the values on each iteration, therefore you only have the values from the last element.

You should bind you data source (`reader`) to an `<asp:Repeater>`'s `DataSource` property. In your markup you specify a header (`HeaderTemplate`), a footer (`FooterTemplate`) and content (`ItemTemplate`). You can omit the header and footer template if you don't need them. You can also use an `AlternatingItemTemplate` if you need to do different things with odd/even rows (e.g. alternating row color in a table).

You can access properties of the databound datatype using the `<%# Eval("SomeProperty") %>` which is a [databinding expression.](https://support.microsoft.com/nb-no/kb/307860#1a)

HTML markup would be something like this:

```
    <asp:Repeater id="Products" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 no-margin product-item-holder hover"> <!-- this div will be repeated for each product -->
            <div class="product-item">
                <div class="image">
                    <img class="img" alt="" src="<%# Eval("Picture") %>" />
                </div>
                <div class="body">
                    <div class="label-discount clear"></div>
                    <div class="title">
                        <a class="name" href="single-product.html"><%# Eval("InventionName") %></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="prices">
                    <div class="price-prev"></div>
                    <div class="price" class="price-current pull-right"><%# Eval("Price") %></div>
                </div>
                <div class="hover-area">
                    <div class="add-cart-button">
                        <a href="single-product.html" class="le-button">Enquiry</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and wire up the datasource in codebehind like this:

```
cn.con.Open();
cn.cmd.Connection = cn.con;
cn.cmd.CommandText = "select * FROM products";
MySqlDataReader reader = cn.cmd.ExecuteReader();

Products.DataSource = reader; // rather than iterating manually, you assign the datasource to the repeater. 
Products.DataBind();

reader.Close();
cn.con.Close();
```

*Side note: I changed the attribute from `id` to `class` on the name, price and img element. Because when this markup is rendered it would have been with multiple elements with the same id, which it shouldn't since `id` is supposed to be unique according to specification.*